# How to get Flink started in FLIP6 mode

Tags: apache-flink

We are using Flink-1.4 on a cluster of 3 machines.
We started the JobManager on one machine with the following command

```
 bin/jobmanager.sh start flip6
```

Next, we started the TaskManager on two machines with the following command:

```
 bin/taskmanager.sh start flip6
```

However, we do not see the Flink Dashboard Web UI up.
Neither do we see any errors in the logs.
Is there something we are missing, maybe in the config file?

Here is the log for the JobManager:
https://gist.github.com/jamesisaactm/72cda2bb286d3a3e20f91e64138941b6

Comment: Would you add error logs too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1.4 the FLIP-6 mode is still a WIP and missing major parts, like the WebUI.

You will have to wait for 1.5 to use the FLIP-6 mode.